# Как сделать более правильный и компактный код в Java

Tags: java, javafx, чистый-код

Есть код:

```
        jsonFile.add("title", new JsonPrimitive(StyleTitle.getText()));
        jsonFile.add("author", new JsonPrimitive(StyleAuthor.getText()));
        jsonFile.add("version", new JsonPrimitive(StyleVersion.getText()));
```

Как его улучшить?

Comment: А чем он сейчас неправильный и некомпактный? Он занимает высоту в три монитора?

Comment: там еще строк 20 таких будет

Comment: нужно больше кода. весь класс хотя бы. слишком мало информации, что бы предложить что-то

Comment: вызов метода getText() у StyleTitle, StyleAuthor, StyleVersion похож на вызов статического метода. если это так, то нужно смотреть эти классы и выяснить, по какой причине там вообще статика. если это просто переменная именованая с большой буквы, то всегда можно имплементировать интерфейс, по вызову методов которого конструировать джейсон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно определить структуру данных, например хэш-таблицу/словарь/список пар "ключ-значение" с ключами-строками и значениями-компонентами `Style`, у которых есть общий метод `getText()`, затем пройтись по этому словарю, добавляя нужные значения и убирая дублированный код.

```java
record Pair(String key, StyleComponent style){}

List<Pair> data = Arrays.asList(
    new Pair("title", StyleTitle),
    new Pair("author", StyleAuthor),
    new Pair("version", StyleVersion) // etc.
);

for (Pair p : data) {
    jsonFile.add(p.key(), new JsonPrimitive(p.getStyle().getText()));
}
```

Comment: или просто содать  POJO класс содержащий (используя  шаблон Builder)  все  необходимые поля  И красиво  будет и молодежно